# Timer doesn't fire after Form closed

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have a .NET form with a `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` declared using the VS designer. The timer works fine. After I close the form, the timer doesn't fire events even if I recreate the Timer object. I've configured the Form to never close using this:

```
    void MainFormFormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        // never close
        e.Cancel = true;

        // only hide
        this.Visible = false;

    }
```

How do I make the timer fire events? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do that you need the Timer firing when the Form is closed?

Comment: Because I show the form later using `this.Visible = true`. I need the timer to fire during that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried this one. **Added** a **WinForms Timer component** on  the form, **start timer on load**, and **debug current time** in *debug window*. Workes fine for me...

```
public frmTimer()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
}
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString());
}
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = true;
    this.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: I finally managed to make it work using a `System.Timers.Timer`.