# continue of timer after closing the form

Tags: c#, winforms, timer

```
var startTime = DateTime.Now;

var timer = new Timer() { Interval = 1000 };

timer.Tick += (obj, args) =>
    label14.Text =
        (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(Convert.ToDouble( comboBox3.Text)*60) - (DateTime.Now - startTime))
        .ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss");
MessageBox.Show("Timer started");
timer.Enabled = true;
```

im strating a timer in a specific form when pressing a button, i want the timer to continue counting time after closing the form in order to give me a notification.
but when closing the form the timer stops,
any ideas?

Comment: make the timer static

Comment: From where are you opening the form?

Comment: You need to define the timer in the proper scope.  Maybe in the main form?

Comment: Can you post a complete code sample that shows the issue. I was not able to duplicate it. Also is it happening during the debugging, or only in executable outside the VS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't "Close" the form and have the Timer object still work (if you're calling the timer on the main form). (That's like saying I can't click the button and have a function run after closing the form). However, on the OnFormClosing argument, you could have the `form.Visible = false` and cancel the actual closing of the form. See here: [Timer doesn't fire after Form closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12230605/timer-doesnt-fire-after-form-closed?rq=1)

If you want to truly close the form and have it run, one option could be to look at possibly creating a Task Scheduler object that would complete the task at a certain time.

Comment: @Rahul No.  The whole application is ending, so that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

A quick hit: call "Hide()" instead - that will keep the timer running.

Now that's out the way, You can still make your timer static - ideally put it in a completely separate class, or, if you insist, make it static on your main form. Then have your notification code sit on your main form.

You can still add a listener to the Tick event on that specific form and just remember to remove it when you hide the form (i.e. `Tick -= your_label_event_handler`)